# How to prove that the derivative of a Lipschitz function is always $\leq$ L

Tags: analysis, limits, derivatives, proof-verification, lipschitz-functions

I'm struggling a bit on how to construct a proof for this question.

Suppose I have a Lipschitz function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ 
that satisfies $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|$ which is differentiable at some point $c\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $f'(c)\leq L$.

I understand the idea behind it. I know that

$$\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$

exists and is finite. I also know that

$$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\leq \left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\right|\leq L$$

and intuitively it makes sense to just take limits of the left-most and right-most term to show that $f'(c)\leq L,$ but why am I allowed to do that? And if it's not possible for me to try that how else would I attempt to prove this?

Comment: "but why am I allowed to do that" It's one of basic properties of limits. If $g(x)\le L$ for all $x$, then $\lim_{x\to c} g(x)\le L$. It can be easily shown with the epsilon-delta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $ |\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}|\leq L$ we get with $x \to c$ that

$|f'(c)| \le L$, hence

$$ f'(c) \le |f'(c)| \le L.$$